# Extracting contents of nested <p> Tags with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am having a hard time using the advantages of beautiful soup for my use case. There are many similar but not always equal nested p tags where I want to get the contents from. Examples as follows:

```
<p><span class="example" data-location="1:20">20</span>normal string</p>
<p><span class="example" data-location="1:21">21</span>this text <strong>belongs together</strong></p>
<p><span class="example" data-location="1:22">22</span>some text (<span class="referencequote">a reference text</span>)that might continue</p>
<p><span class="example" data-location="1:23">23</span>more text</p><div class="linebreak"></div>
<p><span class="example" data-location="1:22">24</span>text with (<span class="referencequote">first</span>)two references <span class="referencequote">first</span>.</p>
```

I need to save the string of the span tag as well as the strings inside the p tag, no matter its styling and if applicable the referencequote. So from examples above I would like to extract:

```
example = 20, text = 'normal string', reference = []
example = 21, text = 'this text belongs together', reference = []
example = 22, text = 'some text that might continue', reference = ['a reference text']
example = 23, text = 'more text', reference = []
example = 24, text = 'text with two references', reference = ['first', 'second']
```

What I was trying is to collect all items with the "example" class and then looping though its parents contents.

```
for span in bs.find_all("span", {"class": "example"}):
    references = []
        for item in span.parent.contents:
            if (type(item) == NavigableString):
                text= item
            elif (item['class'][0]) == 'verse':
                number= int(item.string)
            elif (item['class']) == 'referencequote':
                references.append(item.string)
            else:
                #how to handle <strong> tags?
        verses.append(MyClassObject(n=number, t=text, r=references))
```

My approach is very prone to error and there might be even more tags like `<strong>`, `<em>` that I am ignoring right now. The get_text() method unfortunately gives back sth like '22 some text a reference text that might continue'.

There must be an elegant way to extract this information. Could you give me some ideas for other approaches? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
from simplified_scrapy.core.regex_helper import replaceReg
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc,utils
html = '''
<p><span class="example" data-location="1:20">20</span>normal string</p>
<p><span class="example" data-location="1:21">21</span>this text <strong>belongs together</strong></p>
<p><span class="example" data-location="1:22">22</span>some text (<span class="referencequote">a reference text</span>)that might continue</p>
<p><span class="example" data-location="1:23">23</span>more text</p><div class="linebreak"></div>
<p><span class="example" data-location="1:22">24</span>text with (<span class="referencequote">first</span>)two references <span class="referencequote">second</span>.</p>
'''
html = replaceReg(html,"<[/]*strong>","") # Pretreatment
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
ps = doc.ps
for p in ps:
    text = ''.join(p.spans.nextText())
    text = replaceReg(text,"[()]+","") # Remove ()
    span = p.span # Get first span
    spans = span.getNexts(tag="span").text # Get references
    print (span["class"], span.text, text, spans)
```

Result:

```
example 20 normal string []
example 21 this text belongs together []
example 22 some text that might continue ['a reference text']
example 23 more text []
example 24 text with two references. ['first', 'second']
```

Here are more examples. https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/tree/master/doc_examples

Answer (score 0):

A different approach I found out - without regex and maybe more robust to different spans that might come up

```
    for s in bsItem.select('span'):
        if s['class'][0] == 'example' :
            # do whatever needed with the content of this span 
            s.extract()
        elif s['class'][0] == 'referencequote':
            # do whatever needed with the content of this span 
            s.extract()
       # check for all spans with a class where you want the text excluded

    # finally get all the text
    text = span.parent.text.replace(' ()', '')
```

maybe that approach is of interest for someone reading this :)